# “Largest” symbolic common factor of an integer sequence (not simply GCD)

Tags: symbolic, algorithm, factorization, integer-sequence, asymptotics

Suppose, I have a finite fragment of a quickly increasing sequence of integers $\{a_n\}$ that is too complex, unusual, or irregular for [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to find a general formula or a recurrence relation for it. But suppose that all elements given can be represented as $a_n=10^n\,(2n+1)!!\,n^2\cdot b_n$, where is $10^n\,(2n+1)!!\,n^2$ is a common factor of all elements of the sequence, and $\{b_n\}$ is a more slowly increasing integer sequence (hopefully, more amenable to further analysis). The factor $10^n$ is likely obvious when we look at the sequence, but other factors might require more experimentation or analysis to pull out.

Can anyone suggest an algorithm that tries to find a formula for the “largest” (in the sense of formula complexity or growth rate) symbolic common factor constructed using simple arithmetic operations and combinatorial sequences such as factorial, double factorial, or Catalan numbers?

It is okay if it works on the best-effort basis, leaving some common factors that could be pulled theoretically. This looks like a problem that someone should have already tried to solve before.

Comment: I suggest that you can try using the nonzero integer sequences in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) to test if they divide the given integer sequence.

Comment: Is there a simple way to enumerate OEIS sequences in _Mathematica_?

Comment: You could download [compressed versions](https://oeis.org/wiki/Welcome#Compressed_Versions). of OEIS updated daily.

Comment: It would be nice to have a few examples to experiment.